# How many differnent ways to pick n marbles of five colors at random?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Suppose you have bag of $p$ marbles with $a$ marbles of a color $A$, $b$ of color $B$, and so on to $e$ marbles of $E$ i.e. $p=a+b+c+d+e$. Consequentially for any singular type of marble e.g. $A$, $0\le a \le p$ so long as $p=a+b+c+d+e$.

While there are $\binom{p}{n}$ ways to pick $n$ marbles out of $p$ marbles, I am more interested in figuring out, if given $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, and $e$ how many unique ways there are to do this. For example, suppose $n=2$, $p=10 = a =10, b=c=d=e=0$. There are $\binom{p}{n}$ ways for me to get two marbles, but no matter which two I choose I will have two marbles of type $A$, so there is really only one result.

I guess then my question is more so inverted. Given that I am looking to choose $n$ how many ways can I construct $n$ from $a, b, c, d$, and $e$.

My first thought was the multinomial coefficient

$$
\frac{n!}{a!b!c!d!e!}
$$

but that clearly is incorrect.
What am I forgetting? Looking at this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1665687/how-many-distinct-combinations-of-five-marbles-could-be-drawn) it seems that I have to do this for the variable number of ways this could occur:

$$
5(\binom{n}{n} + \binom{n}{n-1}*4\binom{n}{n-n+1} + \binom{n}{n-2}*8\binom{n}{n-n+1}*4\binom{n}{n-n+2} + \dots)
$$
but that only works assuming that there are $n$ of each type of marble....

Answer (score 5):

You need to be crystal clear about the multinomial coefficients.

For $10$ marbles, if you want $4$ of *a*, $3$ of *b* and one each of $c,d,e,$

the multinomial coefficient $\dfrac{10!}{4!3!1!1!1!}$ indeed gives the answer you desire,

but if you instead specify $3$ of one color, $2$ of another, and $1$ each of the remaining colors, you need to multiply the above by another multinomial coefficient, $\dfrac{5!}{1!1!3!}$ to take into account that the pattern could be generated with different colors in many ways.

The answer could, of course,  be abbreviated as $\dfrac{10!}{4!3!}\cdot\dfrac{5!}{3!}$

but I recommend the full form including $1!$ and (if it occurs), $0!$ to give a sort of double check that the numerator and denominator tally.

---

**Addendum**

Supposing you want at least one of each color, you will first have to form all patterns, eg $6,1,1,1,1\quad5,2,1,1,1\quad4,3,1,1,1\;$(the pattern we discussed), and continue down to $2,2,2,2,2$, compute separately for each case and add up

But there is a shortcut using inclusion-exclusion, viz

$5^{10} - \binom514^{10} + \binom523^{10} - \binom532^{10} + \binom541^{10}$

An even shorter way (if you know about Stirling numbers of the second kind, and have tables of such numbers) is to compute $S2(10,5)*5!$

Comment: So would n!/(a!b!c!d!e!) actually be the general form?

Comment: Sorry what I am specifically asking is how many ways I can make N, given the specific values for a,...,e. Your example (4, 3, 1, 1, 1), is one such outcome for N=10.

Comment: OK, supposing you want at least one of each color, you will first have to form all **patterns**, eg $6,1,1,1,1\; 5,2,1,1,1\; 4,3,1,1,1\;$(the pattern we discussed), and continue down to $2,2,2,2,2$ compute separately for each case and add up. Or there is another way which I am adding in the answer.

Comment: and if it is ok to have 0 of one or more marble colors? Then differ to user's generating function?

Comment: Well, if you can have $0$ of one or more marble colors, then it'll simply be $5^{10}$

Comment: Given that n=10... could you please elaborate on why that is the case? I can't seem to visualize it in my head. That feels wrong if $\vert A \vert < 10$

Comment: You could have $10,0,0,0,0\quad 9,1,0,0,0\quad$ etc

Comment: That assumes there are at least $n$ of at least one color, which isn't necessarily true though

Comment: If there are $4,3,2,1,0$ marbles, only one pattern will be there, $\frac{10}{4!3!2!1!0!}$  We seem to be getting into some other question. If you still have doubts, I suggest you post a new question with features altered to what exactly you want, else it will lead to confusion.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of generating functions the number you are looking for is:
$$
[x^n]\prod_{i=1}^k \sum_{j=0}^{N_i}{x^j},
$$
where $k$ is the number of colors, $N_i$ is the number of marbles of the $i$-th color, and $[x^n]$ denotes the coefficient at $x^n$ in the power expansion of the function.

Answer (score 1):

Adding some explanation to the answer of @user.

Let us embed the question into a Ordinary Generating Function (OGF). See this related question for EGF in case order matters to you: [4 digit combinations of 12333210](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4088242/how-many-different-4-digit-numbers-can-be-made-with-the-digits-from-12333210), [3 letter combinations of MISSISSIPPI](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/960046/number-of-ways-to-choose-a-sequence-of-three-letters-from-the-letters-of-mississ)

**Simpler Problem:** What you need is to find the coefficient of $x^n$ in

$$(1+x+x^2+\dots+x^a)\times(1+x+x^2+\dots+x^b)\times\dots\times(1+x+x^2+\dots+x^e)$$

**Explanation:** The number of ways to pick n marbles of the 5 types, is the same as the number of ways to pick n $x's$ from each of the 5 polynomial sub-expressions. This embedding ensures,

- You can't pick more than $a$ number of x's of type A, and similarly for the other types.
- You pick a total of n $x$'s across the generating polynomials (as you want coefficient of $x^n$).
- You cannot pick a negative number of any type.
- The expression is unique and therefore well-defined.
- Each way of picking $x^n$ from the 5 sub-polynomials adds 1 to the coefficient of $x^n$, and the total number of ways of picking $x^n$ is therefore the coefficient of $x^n$ in the full expression.

Thus the embedding is valid as these above properties are equivalent to the problem you posed.